# Open Drawer by clicking in header of containing StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is the component which contains my Drawer

```
export default class StackInView extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const Stack = StackNavigator({
      DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerInView }
    }, {
        headerMode: 'float',
      });

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Stack />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The following is where I define my button. I want to define the button in navigationOptions of the screen, because the button should only appear on the screen with the drawer. But clicking the button doesn't work can you help me pls?

```
... imports ...


export default class DrawerInView extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Yeah?",
        headerRight: <Button title="Menu" onPress={() => {NavigationActions.navigate("DrawerOpen")}}/>
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
            "one": {
                screen: () => {
                    return (<TabsInView select="something" />)
                },
            },
            "two": {
                screen: () => {
                    return (<TabsInView select="something else" />)
                },
            }
        })
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Drawer />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put Stack into View. It's hard to understand and you break all props.

And the reason it doesn't work is that `navigationOptions` in second code is not for the drawer but for the StackNavigator in the first code. So it can't execute drawer's navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen") because it's StackNavigator's.

And I highly recommend you to change your app's hierarchy. It's really hard that child Drawer passes its navigation to parent Stack's right button.

Then, it would look like this.

```
const MyStack = StackNavigator({
    Tabs:{ screen: MyTabs, navigationOptions:(props) => ({
        headerRight:
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.screenProps.myDrawerNavigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}}>
                <Text>Open Drawer</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    })}
}
, {navigationOptions:commonNavigationOptions})


const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    stack1: {
        screen: ({navigation}) => <MyStack screenProps={{myDrawerNavigation:navigation}} />,
    },
    stack2: {
        //more screen
    }
})
```

Comment: This solution doesn't fit for my Problem, but it helped me anyway. The app will be highly dynamically, so I have to declare the navigator in a render method, so that it is changeable.

Comment: @peni4142 Oh, I get it. Thanks. Hope you achieve what you want. Please let me know if you have other problem for that.

Comment: @peni4142, I'm facing this same issue, please post the solution if you managed to get this to work. Thanks and Regards,

Comment: @AshleyVaz I have no access to the solution anymore. But I think I hat that in a container so the const was created every time. Maybe not the best solution, but it did work.

Answer (score 8):

You can open DrawerNavigation on button click like this.

`<Button title="Menu" onPress ={ ( ) => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />`